# Getting a specific line from a string where the line number I must get is stored in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, sh

I'm trying to get a specific line of a variable. The line I must get is stored in `i`. My code looks like this right now.

`$(echo "$data" | sed '$iq;d')`

It looks like I'm putting `i` in there wrong,  Putting a number in for `i` works fine but `$i` gets me the entire string.

I haven't found a solution that works with a variable yet and I'm not too familiar with bash and would appreciate help,

Edit: a bit of context

`i=5
data=$(netstat -a | grep ESTAB)
line=$(echo "$data" | sed "${i}p")
echo $line`

Comment: @user000001 hmm that just prints out a blank line. I'll edit in a few more lines for context if that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed -n "${i}p"` instead.

Example:

```
i=4; seq 1 10 | sed -n "${i}p"
```

Output:

```
4
```

Bonus:

```
i=5
readarray -O 1 -t data < <(exec netstat -a | grep ESTAB)  ## Stores data as an array of lines starting at index 1
line=${data[i]}
echo "$line"
# printf '%s\n' "${data[@]}"  ## Prints whole data.
```

Comment: Great, that works! Care to explain the difference between yours and the one I attempted? The different quote styles and whatnot confuse me in BASH

Comment: @mbridges First thing was the quoting that you used. Strings in single quotes does not expand variables. The ones in double quotes does. Also, `$iq` is parsed as a single parameter. You should have done `${i}q` at least. It looks like your code works as well only that it needed some adjustments. Final form of it should have been `sed "${i}q;d"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is way you can do this in BASH itself:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($data)
echo "${arr[$i]}"
```